# Gas estimation error - Not sure why

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I made two contracts, one for a simple ERC20 token and then another one to accept that token.

Simple ERC20 Token

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

/**
 * @title SimpleToken
 * @dev Very simple ERC20 Token example, where all tokens are pre-assigned to the creator.
 * Note they can later distribute these tokens as they wish using `transfer` and other
 * `ERC20` functions.
 * Based on https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.1/contracts/examples/SimpleToken.sol
 */
contract SimpleToken is ERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
     */
    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply
    ) public ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

Accept ERC20 Token

```
// contracts/SimpleToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

// Contract that uses any ERC20 token
contract UsingERC20 {
    IERC20 public associatedToken;

    // Constructor. Pass it the token you want this contract to work with
    constructor(IERC20 _token) public {
        associatedToken = _token;
    }
        function approveContract() public {
        associatedToken.approve(address(this), 100000);
    }

    function doSomethingThatRequiresERC20tokens() public {
        // The key here is to use ERC20's transferFrom method.
        // For this to work, the given address has to have enough balance,
        // and it has to allow this contract to transfer tokens from their account.
        // This can be done using ERC20's approve method/

        // If transferFrom fails, the transaction reverts. So if the transaction
        // does not revert, we know that the transer succeeded.

        // Using msg.sender here, the caller of this function.
        // Could be any address you like, though.
        // This transfers 100 tokens from msg.sender to this contract.
        associatedToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 100);

        // Ok, now the tokens are transferred successfully, let's do some cool stuff!
        emit YayIReceivedTokens(100, msg.sender, associatedToken.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    event YayIReceivedTokens(uint256 amount, address fromAccount, uint256 totalBalance);
}
```

I can't find anything wrong with the code itself, made sure that the account I am using to run doSomethingThatRequiresERC20tokens() has the ERC20 token, and also I have linked the contract to the correct ERC20 contract upon initiation. Why its ending up giving me a gas estimation error?

Comment: most likely because the call reverted at some point. include the revert string and we will know

Comment: which function you are calling that gives you the gas estimation error ?can you paste some of your calling code ?

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime calling doSomethingThatRequiresERC20tokens() throws the RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance

Comment: You are transfering tokens that you are not allowed to transfer. your `usingERC20` contract needs to be allowed to transfer `msg.sender` tokens. msg.sender needs to call an approve function of your token to the address of your `usingERC20` contract with the amount needed before you can do the transfer in the `doSomethingThatRequiresERC20tokens`.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime I tried adding an approve function to the usingERC20 contract, and tried calling it before doSomethingThatRequiresERC20tokens function, but still the same gas estimation error.

Comment: @Dunkponi try to put more gas value on the `doSomethingRequiresERC20Tokens` call and see. and leave the approve function it is mandatory.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime I tired 100x of the suggested gas price and it still failed, and that was after running the approved function.